# How to put temporary aliases in a file?

Tags: alias

I can put aliases in my `.bashrc` (or files called from it) and they then work in my shell.

I can also then create other aliases at the command line, e.g.

```
alias aaa='ls'
```

and it works.   `aaa` does an `ls` operation

But if I put that alias definitions in a file, say `aaa_alias`, make it executable and then try and use it, it is not recognized.

I call it with `./aaa_alias` and get no error.  But the aliases does not sem to have been defined in my shell.

Why not?  What am I doing wrong?  How can I have a small number of aliases ina separate file than I just use occasionally when I want and so I invoke it when I went them.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried sourcing the file instead of executing it?

Comment: That is the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to insert the contents of a file into your current session, you need to source the file, not execute it.

```
. my_file
```

When you were just executing the file, the aliases were being set in a subshell and therefore had no effect on your current session.

Comment: Though I imagine this is a duplicate...